# Special character <abc>, angular bracket replace in a .BAT file

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a script in Windows, a .BAT file, to replace: <abc> to abc.
But I'm having problems with the Angular bracket character.

This is how the script looks like:

```
SET STRING=<ABCDEFG>
SET STRING=%STRING:<=%
SET STRING=%STRING:>=%
ECHO String: %STRING%
```

But only got the error message: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

```
 D:\BACKUP>SET STRING=<ABCDEFG>
```

Comment: Please learn how to format code properly; click `edit`, then click the `{}` button in the tool bar of the editor area to see how it works...

Comment: I've edited for you.Accept the edit.

Comment: Commas are not a valid way to separate commands in batch files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Magoo said, special characters need to be escaped.
You can use the caret, but you can use also quotes

```
SET "STRING=<ABCDEFG>"
SET "STRING=%STRING:<=%"
SET "STRING=%STRING:>=%"
ECHO String: "%STRING%"
```

Or better use delayed expansion instead of percent expansion, as delayed expansion can handle any content.

```
SET "STRING=<ABCDEFG>"
SET "STRING=!STRING:<=!"
SET "STRING=!STRING:>=!"
ECHO String: !STRING!
```

Comment: Getting "The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . ." for below code. Please help@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "textFile=C:\toolbase\alm_utils_tmpl_dev\2016.1.0a\abc.txt"
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        SET "STRING=<ABCDEFG>"
SET "STRING=%STRING:<=%"
SET "STRING=%STRING:>=%"
ECHO String: "%STRING%"
)pause

Answer (score 0):

Special characters like redirectors need to be escaped with a caret thus: `^<`

`%` needs to be escaped by `%` thus: `%%`

`&` separates commands on a single line.

Comment: I am not able to replace the string in file.@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "textFile=C:\toolbase\alm_utils_tmpl_dev\2016.1.0a\abc.txt"
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (      
 SET "STRING=<ABCDEFG>"
SET "STRING=%STRING:<=%"
SET "STRING=%STRING:>=%"
ECHO String: "%STRING%"
)
pause.. output : The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
Please help

Comment: @geetha Do not put code into a comment, if you have a new question feel free to open a new thread